# SQLAlchemy classical mapping does not map selected row to instance of model class

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I’m stumped. I really must be missing something basic about how the SQLAlchemy ORM works.

For the same reason I want my Java models to be POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects), I want my Python objects to be independent of the ORM. (Can I call them POPO’s?).

That’s why I’ve chosen to use the SQLAlchemy ORM’s “classical” mapping. The documentation repeatedly states that the declarative and classical mapping methods are equivalent and that, in fact, the former uses the latter under the hood.

The problem is that it ain’t workin’ for me. Specifically, when I do a select to read an object, it’s not being mapped to an instance of my object class. I’m getting back a what my debugger labels a “result” object --a raw row object.

As evidence, I submit two minimal applications. The first one uses declarative mapping and works just fine. My model goes in as a class instance and comes out as one. The second uses classical mapping and my model goes in as a class instances and comes out as a row result.

What am I missing here?

I’m using Python 2.7.10 and SQLAlchemy 1.0.11.

Declarative mapping, which does work:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

thing = Thing()
print "In:  " + str(thing)

session.add(thing)
session.commit()

thing = session.query(Thing).one()
print "Out: " + str(thing)
```

Output:

```
In:  <__main__.Thing object at 0x10c94c490>
Out: <__main__.Thing object at 0x10c94c490>
```

Classical mapping version, which does not work:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, orm

class Thing(object):
    pass

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

metadata = MetaData()

thing_table = Table(
    'thing',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
)

orm.mapper(Thing, thing_table)

metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

thing = Thing()
print "In:  " + str(thing)

session.add(thing)
session.commit()

thing = session.query(thing_table).one()
print "Out: " + str(thing)
```

Output:

```
In:  <__main__.Thing object at 0x10cda2b10>
Out: (1,)
```